# PHP regex to match all img tags except for certain src

Tags: php, regex, xpath, html-parsing, domdocument

I'm very new to PHP and did a slight modification to a certain file in a CMS written in PHP. I modified a function that took the first `<img>` tag in a page source, to take a random tag from that source.

The regex that is used to match the source is:

```
$regex = '/<' . $tag . '\\b[^>]*>/i';
```

where `$tag` just contains a string `img`.

However I've noticed that in the source there are images where the `src` attribute contains "1px.gif" and I don't want to match these.

Currently I keep re-selecting a random element from the array of matches until it is not a 1px.gif, but of course that is a bad solution.

I'm not good enough with regexes to do this on my own but I understand the above regex searches for `<img` and a word character that is not `>`. I need to add "and does not contain '1px.gif'".

Optionally I could check the array of matches and remove every entry that is a 1px.gif but still I would prefer the regex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php/3577662#3577662

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you want to match and what not?

Comment: @MikeB I know regex is discouraged for this purpose, but I cannot simply install PHP extensions like the Simple HTML DOM Parser on the webserver because I don't really know how to make that work with the CMS I'm using...

Comment: @abhi.gupta200297 quite simply, I want to match **all** img tags **except** where the `src` attribute contains the sequence `1px.gif`.

Comment: Extensions are only a short part of that answer - there are many other options available.

Comment: One does not simply parse HTML with regex.

Comment: Regex is not suitable tool to parse HTML because HTML is not regular language.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Will **everybody** stop telling me that regex is not suitable for parsing HTML. **I know that**. It's just the way it is in my situation... I know practically nothing about PHP and it's not worth learning at the moment just because of a tiny improvement on a tiny change I've made to some module of a CMS. The entire module relies on a page's source and I don't know where to go from that to use DOM objects...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of some broken solution (regex cannot parse HTML) you should use DOMDocument to get the data you need. An example of this is:

```
<?php
$html = '<p>something</p><img src="something"><img src="yay"><img src="1px.gif">';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//img[not(contains(@src, "1px.gif"))]');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->getAttribute('src');
}
```

This will get all images which don't have a `src` of `1px.gif`. From there on it would be pretty easy to get a random node.

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/UdEiM4

Comment: Thank you for a constructive answer that a PHP noob like me can understand. I had the entire page source to begin with but I didn't know how to turn it in a `DOMDocument` object, now I do (didn't realise it was that simple).

Comment: The API is pretty straightforward once you know it. The xpath queries may take some time to get familiar with, but once you get it you find out it is very powerful and useful.